# Exeception while running spring jar application file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

Question:

If I run the jar file that I made with the spring application,That Shows an exception that a beans cannot be created. Ironically, it works fine in my local IntelliJ IDE. An exception occurs if I just run it in cmd.

How can I solve this?

-- Exception Log -- (after changed class name : cart)

```
2022-08-27 23:46:58.159  WARN 7816 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'boardController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/controller/BoardController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/service/ItemService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mybatisItemRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/MybatisItemRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/mybatisMapper/ItemMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
2022-08-27 23:46:58.162  INFO 7816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-27 23:46:58.170  INFO 7816 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-27 23:46:58.187 ERROR 7816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'boardController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/controller/BoardController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/service/ItemService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mybatisItemRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/MybatisItemRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/mybatisMapper/ItemMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/service/ItemService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mybatisItemRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/MybatisItemRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/mybatisMapper/ItemMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mybatisItemRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/MybatisItemRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/mybatisMapper/ItemMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip 
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemMapper' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/BoardGameShop/board-1.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/forum/board/repository/mybatisMapper/ItemMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionTemplate' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sqlSessionTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/mybatis/spring/boot/autoconfigure/MybatisAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory]: Factory method 'sqlSessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar!/:5.3.21]
        ... 93 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip 
        ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. The XML location is 'class path resource [mapper/forum/cartMapper.xml]'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 107 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 109 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'cart'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 113 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: cart
        ... skip
        ... 115 common frames omitted
```

(Edit)

I checked the Mybatis log and found that sqlSessionFactoryBean was referring to the mapper xml file in another directory.

I would like to have sqlSessionFactoryBean refer to the mapper.xml that I wrote.

But, I don't know how.

1)application.properties setting

(username and password were hidden for security purposes)
[image]

2)Mybatis Log
[image]

3. mapper.xml Location that I wrote

src > main > resources > mapper > forum > *.xml
[image]

Comment: This is the fundamental error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: Cart`. Make sure the `Cart` class is being included with the application.

Comment: Thank you for leaving comments. First of all, I checked The cart.class file exists inside my spring application built with jar now.

Comment: Java is case sensitive. Ibatis is expecting a class named `Cart`, not `cart`. Also check that `Cart` is in the default package.

Comment: "It's like rain, on your wedding day/An exception in your jar, when your IDE's fine" as Ms. Morissette might have said.

Comment: If the file is indeed named `cart.class`, then that could explain the difference in behavior, assuming you're developing on a platform with a case-insensitive file system (e.g., Windows). If your class is named `Cart` (no package), then Java will look for a file named `Cart.class` on the class-path/module-path. On a case-insensitive file system, this will still find the file named `cart.class`. But the JAR "file system" is _case-sensitive_, meaning the file `Cart.class` does not exist, resulting in a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: So, if that is the problem, then rename your _source file_ from `cart.java` to `Cart.java`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer to my question. However, as you said, I changed the class name to cart and build it to jar, but a similar exception occurred.

Comment: As an aside, you should keep the class name `Cart` as that follows standard Java naming conventions (classes use PascalCase) and rename the source file to match the class name. But if you're still getting a `ClassNotFoundException` where the source file and class have matching names, then I'm not sure what's happening, assuming the class file is being packaged in your JAR file and deployed. Though perhaps the problem is similar to the one in this other Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141920/mybatis-spring-spring-boot-could-not-resolve-type-alias-issue

Comment: Thank you!! The enthusiastic answers helped me so much. I finally found out what was wrong. It is presumed to have been because sqlSessionFactoryBeans was parsing the mapper.xml file from a strange directory.